# How do I time delay a job in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, queue

Let's say my server sends an identical request to 5 client devices at 12:00:05. I want to wait 90 seconds (until 12:01:35) and then check which clients have responded appropriately to the request and do some other stuff. What's the best way to accomplish something like this?

Should I queue up a job and use `sleep(90)` at the beginning? The problem is this type of job will always take at least 90 seconds to complete and the server is set by default to time out after 60 seconds. I suppose I can change the server setting, but my other jobs should still be considered to have timed out if they get past 60 seconds.

Should I queue up a scheduled task instead? The problem here is I think Laravel and cron only give you scheduling precision to the nearest minute (12:01 or 12:02, but not 12:01:35).

Comment: What about submitting the job to the queue "delayed dispatch"?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use delayed dispatching for your queues in Laravel . https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#delayed-dispatching

```
$job = (new YourEvent($coolEvent))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(90));
```

This will run the task 90 seconds after it's added to queue.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. Not sure how I missed that in the docs.

Comment: I know this question is 5 years old but since it's related and it's the first result from a search engine, is there a way to delay the task until a set date in time?

Comment: @Wanjia isn't it the same way? If you calculate the time difference between the set date and now, you can use the same delay functionality.