# Laravel, limit database queue to 1 email per minute

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-8, cron-task

My application is hosted on a shared hosting platform that limits to 200 emails per hour.
My application is running *database connection driver* and I have 3000 jobs in the jobs table.
I would like to throttle this queue to only send 1 email every 30 secs or 1 minute to ensure I don't run issues with my hosting.

**Research**:
I have tried delay from [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delay-between-processes-in-job-queue), rate limiting from [this question with no response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645204/rate-limiting-queued-mail-in-laravel-8), delayed jobs from [this laravel documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#delayed-jobs) but nothing works.

**Question:** Is there a way to throttle the queue in *database queue connection* like they do it in *redis queue connection* i.e

```
// Allow only 1 email every 30 seconds
Redis::throttle('any_key')->allow(1)->every(30)->then(function () {
    Mail::to($this->email)->send(new NotificationEmail($this->data) );
    Log::info('Emailed order ' . $this->email);
}, function () {
    // Could not obtain lock; this job will be re-queued
    return $this->release(2);
});
```

**My implementation:** Delays only for the first job then sends the others with no delay

```
public function sendEmailNotification($email,$data)
{
    //Send email to user and to admin
    $email_job = (new ProcessEmailNotificationJob($email,$data))->delay(now()->addSeconds(30));
    
    if($this->dispatch($email_job)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ENV File: **

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Make a command that only dispatches one job when it's ran. In `App/Console/Kernel.php` register that command and schedule it for every 30 secs or 1 minute. That's how we've set it up for running one job every x seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I time delay a job in Laravel 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582935/how-do-i-time-delay-a-job-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: @BhimaniRutvik This tutorial suggests exactly what I've used. This solution only delays the first email then sends the rest without delay as explained in my post

Comment: @geertjanknapen thank you, but that command will have to be called by a cron job every 30 seconds for it to fire and my shared host has a minimum of 5 minutes. Each email might be sent every 5 minutes.

Comment: @Lefty Okay, well depending on the use case, you should consider if 5 minutes works for you. Otherwise you could look at the answer below and maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

did you run **php artisan queue:listen**, if yes check my below code maybe it will help

**inside your controller:**

```
$mail = (
    [
       'data' => $EmailData,
       'userName' => $userData->first_name,
       'userMail' => $userData->email,
       'subject' => $subject
    ]);
                    
SendMailJob::dispatch($mail)
    ->delay(now()->addSeconds($waitSec));
$waitSec += 30; //seconds interval
```

**SendMailJob class**

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Mail\ClientRegistrationNotification;
use Mail;
class SendMailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $bulkMail, $mail;
    public function __construct($Mail)
    {
        $this->mail=$Mail;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try  {
                Mail::to($this->mail['userMail'])
                     ->queue(new ClientRegistrationNotification($this->mail['data'], $this->mail['userName'], $this->mail['userMail'], $this->mail['subject']));

             } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
                $this->fail();
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using a for loop inside the controller method before dispatching?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best option but the only solution that worked for me was sleeping the queue for 30 seconds after dispatch i.e

**Dispatch Method**

```
public function sendEmailNotification($email,$data)
{
    //Dispatch all 3000 with no delay
    if(ProcessEmailNotificationJob::dispatch($email,$data)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Sleep Queue Sender**

```
class ProcessEmailNotificationJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $email;
    private $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email,$data)
    {
        //
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //Send the Mail and sleep for 30 Seconds before sending the next one
        sleep(30);
        Mail::to($this->email)->send(new NotificationEmail($this->data) );

    }
}
```